# Templates from C++ in C

Tags: c++, c, templates, macros, multiple-definition-error

I am trying to recreate some classes from the C++ standard library in C. For example, the std::pair class.
To emulate templates, I used macros of course. Here is an example of how it looks like:

```
#define _TEMPLATE_PAIR_STRUCT(T1, T2, TNAME, STRNAME) \
typedef struct {                                  \
    T1* first;                                    \
    T2* second;                                   \
} STRNAME;

#define _TEMPLATE_PAIR_NEW(T1, T2, TNAME, STRNAME) \
    STRNAME* TNAME##_new()                         \
    {                                              \
        STRNAME *new = malloc(sizeof( STRNAME ));  \
        new->first = malloc(sizeof(T1));           \
        new->second = malloc(sizeof(T2));          \
        return new;                                \
    }
```

If I am trying to use this structure in multiple source files, I have to generate the code multiple times. That, obviously, leads to an error.

Is there a way to fix this, so I can use these "templates" in C?

Comment: have you ever heard of `#ifndef #define ` and include gaurd : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard ?

Comment: Why not just program in C++?

Comment: Hah, I've seen this sort of method in some proper C projects. Meh, why not. You just have to be careful to get the one-definition thing right. You'll probably need multiple files.

Comment: @0x90 As far as I know, #define is not global, it's only visible inside a single source file.

Comment: @ undefined behaviour: I would prefer to do so but I am forced to use C.

Comment: @AndreasT Then program in C. This is *not* C.

Comment: @H2CO3 How does my code violate the definition of the C language?

Comment: @AndreasT Not the definition - the philosophy.

Comment: Marking the function with __attribute__((weak)) would probably cause multiple definitions to be elided with no complaints from the linker (assuming GCC and ELF binaries), not that you want to do this...

Comment: @H2C03 - I think C has broader flexibility than you see it as having.

Comment: @AndyThomas-Cramer I didn't say doing this is impossible. I'd just don't recommend it. (Well, actually, I strongly oppose it, this is not nice C style. The R from K&R is rolling over in his grave...)

Comment: @0x90 you realize that include guards wouldn't actually solve the problem, yes?

Comment: @jalf can you please explain why not?

Comment: @0x90 Include guards protect against the same code being included multiple times *in the same* source file (because it indirectly includes the same header multiple times). It does not protect against the same code being included into multiple source files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As others have said, there are a few things to keep in mind, mainly make sure there is only one function definition.

I don't particularly like this solution but here it is.

One header to rule them all (pair.h)

```
#ifndef TEMPLATE_PAIR
#define TEMPLATE_PAIR

#include <stdlib.h>

#define PAIR_NAME( T1, T2 ) T1##T2##NAME
#define PAIR_PTR_NAME( T1, T2 ) T1##T2##PTR_NAME

#define PAIR_CREATE( T1, T2) MAKE##T1##T2
#define PAIR_PTR_CREATE( T1, T2) MAKE_PTR##T1##T2

#define PAIR_PTR_FREE(T1, T2) FREE##T1##T2

#define PAIR_DEFINITION( T1, T2) \
    typedef struct { \
    T1 first; \
    T2 second ; \
    } PAIR_NAME(T1, T2)

#define PAIR_PTR_DEFINITION( T1, T2) \
    typedef struct { \
    T1* first; \
    T2* second ; \
    } PAIR_PTR_NAME(T1, T2)

#define MAKE_PAIR_DECLARE(T1, T2) PAIR_NAME(T1, T2) PAIR_CREATE(T1, T2) ( const T1& V1, const T2& V2 )
#define MAKE_PAIR_PTR_DECLARE(T1, T2) PAIR_PTR_NAME(T1, T2) PAIR_PTR_CREATE(T1, T2) ( const T1& V1, const T2& V2 )
#define PAIR_PTR_FREE_DECLARE(T1, T2) void PAIR_PTR_FREE(T1, T2) ( PAIR_PTR_NAME(T1, T2) & Pair )

#define MAKE_PAIR_SIGNATURE(T1, T2) PAIR_NAME(T1, T2) PAIR_CREATE(T1, T2) ( const T1& V1, const T2& V2 )
#define MAKE_PAIR_PTR_SIGNATURE(T1, T2) PAIR_PTR_NAME(T1, T2) PAIR_PTR_CREATE(T1, T2) ( const T1& V1, const T2& V2 )

#define FREE_PAIR_PTR_SIGNATURE(T1, T2) void PAIR_PTR_FREE(T1, T2) ( PAIR_PTR_NAME(T1, T2) & Pair )

#define MAKE_PAIR_DEFINE( T1, T2 ) \
    MAKE_PAIR_SIGNATURE(T1, T2) { \
        PAIR_NAME(T1, T2) pair; \
        pair.first = V1; \
        pair.second = V2; \
        return pair; \
        }

#define MAKE_PAIR_PTR_DEFINE( T1, T2 ) \
    MAKE_PAIR_PTR_SIGNATURE(T1, T2) { \
        PAIR_PTR_NAME(T1, T2) pair; \
        pair.first = malloc( sizeof(T1) ); \
        if ( pair.first != 0 ) *(pair.first) = V1; \
        pair.second = malloc( sizeof( T2) ) ; \
        if ( pair.second != 0 ) *(pair.second) = V2; \
        return pair; \
        }

#define PAIR_PTR_FREE_DEFINE( T1, T2 ) \
    FREE_PAIR_PTR_SIGNATURE(T1, T2) { \
    free( Pair.first ); \
    free( Pair.second ); \
    }

#endif
```

One header to bring them all (defs.h):

```
#ifndef DEFS_HEADER
#define DEFS_HEADER

#include "pair.h"

typedef int* pInt;

PAIR_DEFINITION( int, int );
PAIR_DEFINITION( int, double );
PAIR_DEFINITION( double, double );
PAIR_DEFINITION( pInt, pInt );
PAIR_DEFINITION( float, int );

PAIR_PTR_DEFINITION( int, int );

MAKE_PAIR_DECLARE( int, int );
MAKE_PAIR_DECLARE( int, double );
MAKE_PAIR_DECLARE( double, double );
MAKE_PAIR_DECLARE( pInt, pInt );
MAKE_PAIR_DECLARE( float, int );

MAKE_PAIR_PTR_DECLARE( int, int );
PAIR_PTR_FREE_DECLARE( int, int );

#endif
```

And in the darkness bind them (impl.c):

```
#include "defs.h"

MAKE_PAIR_DEFINE( int, int );
MAKE_PAIR_DEFINE( int, double );
MAKE_PAIR_DEFINE( double, double );
MAKE_PAIR_DEFINE( pInt, pInt );

// manual "instantiation"
MAKE_PAIR_SIGNATURE( float, int )
{
    PAIR_NAME( float, int ) local;

    local.first = V1;
    local.second = V2;
    return local;
}

MAKE_PAIR_PTR_DEFINE( int, int );
PAIR_PTR_FREE_DEFINE( int, int );
```

In the land of main where the shadows lie:

```
#include "defs.h"


int main(void)
{
    PAIR_NAME(int, int) myPairInts;
    PAIR_NAME( double, double) myPairDoubles;
    PAIR_NAME( pInt, pInt) myPairPointers;
    PAIR_NAME( float, int) myPairOther;

    PAIR_PTR_NAME( int, int ) pairPtr;


    myPairInts = PAIR_CREATE( int, int ) (1, 2);
    myPairDoubles = PAIR_CREATE( double, double ) (5, 6.5);
    myPairPointers = PAIR_CREATE( pInt, pInt) ( 0, 0 );
    myPairOther = PAIR_CREATE( float, int) (1, 1);

    pairPtr = PAIR_PTR_CREATE(int, int) (1, 2 );

    PAIR_PTR_FREE(int, int) (pairPtr );


    return 0;
}
```

`PAIR_NAME` creates a structure containing values, `PAIR_PTR_NAME` contains pointers to values. `PAIR_CREATE` and `PAIR_PTR_CREATE` create values and fill the data inside the pair.

You will need to define all the necessary combinations in "impl.c". Any compilation unit can `#include "defs.h"` and use the pairs.

EDIT - Answers to questions:

1. "Wouldn't this cause trouble when I use this once in a library or something of that kind and then again in a program which uses both that library and the pair "template"?"

"pair.h" contains only macros, it can be safely used in any library or program.

What's important is that you don't define the same function twice. I wouldn't define the same structure twice either.

You can do the following though:
- take pair.h, defs.h and impl.c as they are above and build them into a library (add any necessary `__declspec(dllexport)` and `__declspec(dllimport`)
- you can then `#include pair.h` and `defs.h` and use the pairs defined there in a program
- if you want to use new pairs, say for `(float, float)` you will need to add a new `defs_my_program.h` and a new `impl_my_program.c` to declare and define these new pair. The `defs_my_program.h` header can be included along with  the `defs.h` header the library provides.

You still get one declaration and one definition for each pair. The only "downside" is that you can't really (safely) use pairs on-the-fly, they need to be centralized.

1. "The way you chose the type and function names to be does bring some issues with it. You split up a pair with two values and one with two pointers. You would also need a specialisation for a pair with one pointer and one value, and for a pair with one value and one pointer. So I would have 4 cases of pairs already. Using this for triplets or even higher tuples, I would have to implement 2^n cases."

Well, for starters, you asked for `std::pair` and not for a touple.

Note that `std::pair` is the equivalent of `PAIR_NAME`, there is no `std::pair` that allocates dynamic memory.

You don't need any new specializations if you don't need to automatically use `malloc`. The example with `pInt` shows that you can create s `pair` of `(int, int*)` or `(int*, int)`. It's just that the *value* of the pointer needs to come from outside the `pair`.

If you really want a `pair` of `(int, int*)` that automatically allocates memory for the `int*` you will have to add it yourself *if you actually need it*. I hope you will not.

For tuples of values, a not very optimal solution could be to use a `pair` of a `pair` and another element. This would give you a structure containing three elements. Something like that can probably be done via macro magics, cutting down on that exponential growth you are worried about.

Comment: Sorry to ask again but I want to make sure I understood your code correctly:
You split up the macros into one for declaration and one for definition. So I can use the macro for declaration like an include in source files and for the definition, I add another source file. I have two questions though:

Comment: 1. Wouldn't this cause trouble when I use this once in a library or something of that kind and then again in a program which uses both that library and the pair "template"?

Comment: 2. The way you chose the type and function names to be does bring some issues with it. You split up a pair with two values and one with two pointers. You would also need a specialisation for a pair with one pointer and one value, and for a pair with one value and one pointer. So I would have 4 cases of pairs already. Using this for triplets or even higher tuples, I would have to implement 2^n cases.

Comment: The pInt example is correct, yes, but I would find it a bit annoying to use a typedef everytime. Anyway, I guess this is the best solution, so thanks a lot. Though, this is much more complex than what I had in mind at first, so I'll have to see if this is even worth the additional work.

Answer (score 2):

Declaring the struct multiple time is not a problem.

Defining the function multiple time is a problem.  If you make the function static then it becomes a once per file issue.  Even in C++ sometimes people will explicitly instantiate templates.  You can have one file that has all the new functions.

If you want an automatic solution, then you need to look at how C++ compilers instantiate templates.
Here is one method that was used ages ago.

- Compile and link your code with no uses of PAIR_NEW
- You will get undefined _new() functions.
- Run a script that generates a C file with the proper PAIR_NEW() macro calls to define the undefined symbols
- compile this new file and relink your project including the new file.

Comment: +1 for noting the need to make the function static, if the macro is applied to the same type in more than one source file.

Comment: Are you saying that a combination of declaring those functions as static and include guards would to the trick? Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @AndreasT Making the function static just makes the problem happen less often.  Include guards do not help at all.  Your header has only #define and it is legal to do the same #define multiple times.

Comment: @brianbeuning True, I thought about using include guards inside the definition macro, but that isn't possible.

Answer (score 1):

Abstracting from the question if it is a good idea, you have several things wrong in your implementation.

- never hide a `;` inside a macro, this is completely against visual expectations at the place this would be used.
- other than in C++, a function that doesn't receive a parameter should
  have `void` inside the `()`.
- names starting with an underscore and a capital letter are reserved
  for the C implementation in all contexts. Chose a better naming
  convention.
- other than in C++ your `new` function wouldn't initialize the data,
  this is a bad naming convention, too.
- you are using the identifier `new` as a local variable, bad if you
  want to interface this to some C++ one day
- your macro for the function should split into three parts: (1) for
  the naming convention that plugs together the name of the function,
  (2) an `inline` definition and (3) an external "instantion" that lets
  you generate the function symbol in exactly one compilation unit.

Comment: The question wasn't really if it's a good idea but how to fix the described problem.

Anyway:

Comment: 1. I guess you are refering to the ; after the definition of the struct? Well, I would agree with you if this was a macro which I would use as a command inside a function. These macros, however, are to be used outside and therefore should not require a ; afterwards.

Comment: 3. Isn't the double underscore for the C implementation and single underscores for other "invisible" implementations? I've seen libraries use a leading underscore for internal functions.

Comment: 4. There is not much I can do about the data not being initialized, is there? I don't see why the naming convention is bad, I find it rather intuitive.

Comment: 5. Why would I want to interface a worse copy of a C++ class to C++?

Comment: 6. Sorry, I don't understand what you mean, especially not (3).

Comment: @AndreasT Section 7.1.3 of the C standard says "All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another
underscore are always reserved for any use". So that's that.

Comment: @AndreasT, to understand (3) you'd have to look into how `inline` functions work in C. They are a bit different from C++. The naming convention is bad, because you are not constructing anything, only allocating. You should call it `_alloc` or something like that. In any case, to make it a viable replacement for C++ templates in some sense, you'd have to implement things much more carefully.